# Could not build module 'SFMCSDK' & module 'MarketingCloudSDK'

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, compile-error, compile, xcode

it's Ian, an iOS dev.

My client wants to migrate the push notifications campaigns management of their iOS and Android apps to Salesforce.

I'm facing **compile issues** after adding the marketing libraries when we try to archive and ship the project to the AppStore using **MarketingCloudSDK v8.0.10** & **SFMCSDK v1.0.6** ([Option 2: Implement the SDK manually](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-addsdk.html)). However, running the app in the simulator has worked a few times using older SDK versions.

1. Add MarketingCloudSDK.xcframework [v8.0.10](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/releases) to project Libraries
2. Add SFMCSDK.xcframework [v1.0.6](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/sfmc-sdk-ios/releases) to project Libraries.
3. Add MarketingCloudSDK.bundle to Copy Bundle Resources

   - File from `MarketingCloudSDK-iOS-8.0.10/Sources/MarketingCloudSDKResources/Resources/MarketingCloudSDK.bundle`

[image: Archive errors]

Do you have any news on how to fix it? I've seen people having similar issues.

- [Getting error while building in xcode error: non-portable path to file](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/383341/getting-error-while-building-in-xcode-error-non-portable-path-to-file)
- [Next-gen Migration from MarketingCloudSDK 7.6 to 8.0.x](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/376571/next-gen-migration-from-marketingcloudsdk-7-6-to-8-0-x)
- [No such module "SFMCSDK" after migrating to v8](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/375780/no-such-module-sfmcsdk-after-migrating-to-v8)
- [MarketingCloudSDK iOS 8.0.2 - Unable to upload to App Store Connect](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/365663/marketingcloudsdk-ios-8-0-2-unable-to-upload-to-app-store-connect)

#### Environments

###### My development computer

- Macbook Pro 16" with Intel CUs (i9)

  - 8 CPU @ 2.4GHz
  - 64 GB RAM

###### Circle CI

- MacOS machines with Intel CPUs

  - 4 CPU @ 3.2 GHZ
  - 8 GB RAM

[image: CircleCI deploy job]

#### Error logs

```
/Users/ian/Projects/Xcode/.../<module-includes>:2:9: Non-portable path to file '"Headers/SFMCSdk-Swift.h"'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk

/Users/ian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MarketingCloudSDK.framework/Headers/MarketingCloudSDK+Base.h:12:9: Could not build module 'SFMCSDK'

Could not build Objective-C module 'MarketingCloudSDK'
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.

### Updates after receiving feedback

Neither the project nor the target app treats the warnings as errors.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting "Treat Warnings as Errors" to "No?"

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply @EthanYehuda. 

Looking at the Build settings of the app, it seems the **warnings are not treated as errors**. I've added a screenshot to the Question description.

Would it be possible to make a quick Teams call this week? Looking at the GitHub repositories, it seems you are the ideal Salesforce iOS SDK developer to ask doubts.

My client has a few million users in the UK, so I'm sure we can work out something. Their platforms already use Salesforce for email marketing. Therefore, there's an existing contract between both companies.

Comment: Please ensure this setting is set to no for "Apple Clang - Warning Policies" and "Swift Compiler - Warning Policies." If you still have issues, please open a support ticket.

Comment: Hi @EthanYehuda, many thanks for your support. 

Thanks to your latest suggestion, I got rid of the compile errors. 
I've just posted a solution with all the steps I followed. Hopefully, it will help any other iOS devs integrate the SDK manually .

Comment: We're hoping to address the header warnings so users of the SDK can enable these flags. Say tuned and thanks for your detailed response!

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

Hi, it's Ian again. I just wanted to share a few notes after integrating the **MarketingCloudSDK v8.0.10** & **SFMCSDK v1.0.6** successfully into my client's iOS app.

##### Treat Warnings as Errors

No treating warnings as errors in both ***Apple Clang - Warning Policies*** and ***Swift Compiler - Warning Policies*** was the major error cause. [@Ethan Yehuda](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/116901/ethan-yehuda), many thanks for pointing this out.

[image: Treat warnings as errors in Build Settings]

##### Embed & Sign Salesforce SDKs

I got a few errors when I picked *Do not Embed* or *Embed without signing*. Now, we **Embed & Sign** both SDKs.

[image: Xcode - Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content]

##### Supported Platforms

After uploading the new build to TestFlight, we received an email from Apple warning us about the lacking MacOS support by two frameworks.

[image: AppleStore Connect email]

Therefore, we stopped the distribution of this app for MacOS. Both in the AppStore:

[image: AppStore Connect - Pricing and Availability]

And removed MacOS (Designed for iPad) from Xcode's project-supported destinations:

[image]

For example, the *Firebase* SDKs support iOS, MacOS, and tvOS.

[image: Firebase XCFrameworks]

Whereas the *MarketingCloudSDK* & the *SFMCSDK* only support iOS.

[image: Salesforce MarketingCloudSDK XCFramework]

It might be good to precompile this SDK for MacOS so we can distribute the iPad version of the app into the MacOS AppStore.

##### MarketingCloudSDK.bundle

I also doubted which bundle file to use in the SDK 8 major version since there were two files, one in `/MarketingCloudSDK` (Opt 1) and another in `/Sources/MarketingCloudSDKResources/Resources` (Opt 2) with slightly different KB sizes.

In the end, I used Option 1.

[image: MarketingCloudSDK.bundle files]

#### Alternative

Using the precompiled XCFrameworks of **MarketingCloudSDK v7.6.0** & **SFMCSDK v1.0.0** didn't give me any of the mentioned issues.

Based on my experience, I'd recommend starting integrating the  MarketingCloudSDK v7.6.0, and once you receive a push successfully, upgrade it to its latest v8.x.y version.

Comment: Please update to the latest release (MarketingCloudSDK 8.0.12 & SFMCSDK 1.0.8)

Comment: @EthanYehuda, many thanks for letting us know about the new versions. We've added them to the project.

Can we treat warnings as errors again?